# Animating a line being drawn over time using plain javascript (without Raphael or other plugins)

Tags: javascript, animation, line

I am trying to show the animation of a line being drawn, draw an line inside an SVG element.

Similar questions have answers which point to the Raphael JS library.
I however, cannot use any libraries available on the internet due to limitations.

Some pointers on how to do this in JS would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't know where to start. Because, everywhere I search points to some library. I am reading http://www.schillmania.com/content/projects/javascript-animation-1/ currently.

Comment: 'closed as not a real question' by users who have no interest in animating paths in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never, ever worked with SVG in my live, yet in 10 minutes after a quick google I came up with:

```
<svg width=200 height=200>
    <line id="myLine" x1="5" y1="10" x2="5" y2="10" stroke-width=".5" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
<script>
var line = document.getElementById('myLine');
var count = 0;
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    line.setAttribute('y2', 2 + +line.getAttribute('y2'));
    line.setAttribute('x2', 1 + +line.getAttribute('x2'));
    if (count++ > 75)
        window.clearInterval(interval);
}, 100);
</script>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/YSmDH/

Comment: Thank you. I did search.

Comment: Hi RoToRa, can you please tell me what 2 + + does?

Comment: The second `+` is the unary plus operator. It's a short cut to convert a string into a number. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `<canvas id='mycanvas' width='300' height='300' />` element and draw your line like this:

```
function drawShape(){
  // get the canvas element using the DOM
  var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');

  // Make sure we don't execute when canvas isn't supported
  if (canvas.getContext){

   // use getContext to use the canvas for drawing
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

   // Stroked triangle
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(125,125);
   ctx.lineTo(125,45);
   ctx.lineTo(45,125);
   ctx.closePath();
   ctx.stroke();

  }
}
```

By adding a [timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) and [clearing](http://simonsarris.com/blog/346-how-you-clear-your-canvas-matters) your 2D-Context and afterwards creating it new, you can animate your line

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial) is a very good tutorial for canvas manipulation.

Comment: Hi Jan, Thanks. But I do know how to draw lines inside Canvas/SVG. I am trying to animate the drawing process, and thats what my question is about.

Comment: @Prashanth Subramanian Iyer: See additions.